# Updating an integer array using a keypad

Tags: arduino

```
int update() //funtion for updating   
{
  int i=0;  
  lcd.clear();  
  lcd.print("Welcome");  
  while(1){  
    if(num=keypad.getKey())  //
    {
      a[i]=num;  
      lcd.clear();  
      lcd.print('*');  
      i=i+1;  
      if(i==4)   
        goto no;  
    }  
  }  
  no:  
  return 0;           
}
```

I have a globally declared array

```
a[]={1,2,2,3,4}
```

I need to update this array using input from the keypad.I've done this by    calling the function update from my void loop(). But no matter what I do, I  can't update it. Whats wrong?

I'm new to arduino. Can anyone suggest how to do this.

Comment: Please always ensure correct formatting (code and text) to allow others to actually understand and answer your question. Always remember to first do your own work before asking others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will keypad.getKey() return if nothing is pressed? I will assume it will return -1 when nothing is pressed.

```
int update() //funtion for updating   
{ 
    int i=0; //intialize i
    int num; //declare num
    lcd.clear();  
    lcd.print("Welcome");  
    while(1)
    {
        num=keypad.getKey();
        if(num != -1)  //Test if any button is pressed
        {
            a[i]=num;  
            lcd.clear();  
            lcd.print('*');  
            i=i+1;  
            if(i==4) return 0;
            delay(500); //delay so multiple values aren't added to array for single press     
        }
    }  
}
```